# Formulate Confusion Matrix from Precision Score

Tags: classification, multiclass-classification, data-analysis, confusion-matrix

I have the precision scores from 5 classes. Is it possible to create the confusion matrix from that scores. While running the code, I only saved those precision values by mistake. So now I want to calculate the confusion matrix from those precision values. Is it possible ? For testing 1400 samples were used.

The precision score of 5 classes:

```
A > 86.78   
B > 85.92
C > 83.21   
D > 83.5
E > 82.73
```

Comment: What are the individual class break-up of 1400.

Comment: 280 on each class